# ggplot2 for-loop set predetermined opacity

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

| students | test_number | grade | date | Annotation | opacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 1 | 93.71243933 | 1/12/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jack | 2 | 93.99600357 | 1/13/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jack | 3 | 84.10703428 | 1/14/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jack | 4 | 84.42595086 | 1/15/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jill | 1 | 90.39846334 | 2/15/20 | Math | 0.5 |
| Jill | 2 | 88.85106545 | 2/16/20 | Math | 0.5 |
| Jill | 3 | 86.96371933 | 2/17/20 | Math | 0.5 |
| Jill | 4 | 93.6563491 | 2/18/20 | Math | 0.5 |
| Jake | 1 | 81.99231127 | 1/11/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jake | 2 | 97.84547146 | 1/12/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jake | 3 | 89.19210496 | 1/13/20 | Math | 1 |
| Jake | 4 | 98.40396283 | 1/14/20 | Math | 1 |
| Phill | 1 | 87.14411612 | 1/12/20 | Math | 0.2 |
| Phill | 2 | 85.35117176 | 1/13/20 | Math | 0.2 |
| Phill | 3 | 88.46359121 | 1/14/20 | Math | 0.2 |
| Phill | 4 | 86.6323419 | 1/15/20 | Math | 0.2 |

And a ggplot loop which generates a pdf, a page per plot of each student:

```
plot_list = list()
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  p = ggplot(all_students[all_students$students==var,], aes(x=test_number, y=grade, group=Annotation)) +
    geom_line()+           
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(var) +
    scale_shape(guide = FALSE) +
    xlab("Test Date + Number")
  plot_list[[var]] = p
}
pdf("all_students.pdf")
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  print(plot_list[[var]])
}
dev.off()
```

I'm trying to set the opacity of the line to be based off the `opacity` column. I've tried:

`scale_alpha_manual(values = opacity) +`

But it is not working, saying no object `opacity`.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Don't you need `all_students$opacity`?

Comment: @tolik518 I've tried that as well, I got `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): alpha`

Comment: Thanks @stefan, but now I'm getting `Error in rgb[, 4] : incorrect number of dimensions` when running the print loop

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your desired result by mapping your `opacity` column on the `alpha` aes. Additionally you have to add `scale_alpha_identity` to use the opacity values stored in the `opacity` column. Otherwise ggplot2 will pick the alpha values for you.

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_list <- list()
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  p <- ggplot(all_students[all_students$students == var, ], aes(x = test_number, y = grade, group = Annotation)) +
    geom_line(aes(alpha = opacity)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_alpha_identity() +
    ggtitle(var) +
    scale_shape(guide = "none") +
    xlab("Test Date + Number")
  plot_list[[var]] <- p
}

plot_list[[4]]
```

[image]

```r
pdf(tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"))
for (var in unique(all_students$students)) {
  print(plot_list[[var]])
}
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

**DATA**

```
all_students <- structure(list(students = c(
  "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jill",
  "Jill", "Jill", "Jill", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake", "Jake", "Phill",
  "Phill", "Phill", "Phill"
), test_number = c(
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L,
  2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), grade = c(
  93.71243933,
  93.99600357, 84.10703428, 84.42595086, 90.39846334, 88.85106545,
  86.96371933, 93.6563491, 81.99231127, 97.84547146, 89.19210496,
  98.40396283, 87.14411612, 85.35117176, 88.46359121, 86.6323419
), date = c(
  "1/12/20", "1/13/20", "1/14/20", "1/15/20", "2/15/20",
  "2/16/20", "2/17/20", "2/18/20", "1/11/20", "1/12/20", "1/13/20",
  "1/14/20", "1/12/20", "1/13/20", "1/14/20", "1/15/20"
), Annotation = c(
  "Math",
  "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math",
  "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math"
), opacity = c(
  1,
  1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -16L
))
```